# show the maximum value of a column of mysql table in php?

Tags: php

I want to show the maximum value of a particular column of mysql table in php. Here is my code:

```
  <?php
         mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
         mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

         $var = $_POST['value'];
         $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT MAX(column) FROM tableName WHERE variable='$var' ") or die(mysql_error());

         $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) or die(mysql_error());

         echo "Maximum value is ::  ".$row['column'];
    ?>
```

output:::

```
    Maximum value is ::
```

Comment: This most probably means your WHERE condition does not return any rows.

Comment: `$row['MAX(column)']` or `$row[0]` both will work but not `$row['column']`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could be a bit creative:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `column` FROM tableName WHERE variable='$var' ORDER BY `column` DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Yeah, explicitly selecting all the records and than just get first one. :)

Comment: i like this style hehe improper but it is same

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem that I was searching for a solution. The approach below worked. The solution was using "*MYSQLI_NUM*". While the code below gives the intended result it still seems way too complex. Is there a way to "short-cut" using the "while" statement to search an array since there is only one returned value?

Selecting a max value only returns one number, yet PHP still seems to require a loop to evaluate an entire array. I was expecting something easy, like: max_value=result(0).

```
<?php

    require_once 'login.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error.'   Sorry, could not connect to the database server');

        $query = "SELECT MAX(IssueIDNUM) FROM tblIssueList";

        $result =$conn->query($query);  
        if (!$result) die($conn->error);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) 
        {
            $maxresult=$row[0];
            echo $maxresult;            
         }  

    $result->close();
    $conn->close();

?>
```

With further experimentation, I was also able to adapt the code by Jim H. to develop the following solution. Though it works the code still seems too complex.

```
// Solution #2
        $result =$conn->query("SELECT MAX(IssueIDNUM) `max` FROM tblIssueList");      
        if (!$result) die($conn->error);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo $row['max'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The real name of column is `MAX(column)`, try:

```
print_r($row);
```

You may either do:

```
$sql = mysql_query(" SELECT MAX(column) AS `column` FROM tableName WHERE variable='$var' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Or:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "Maximum value is ::  ".$row[0];
```

Comment: How can i use another column by this query.

Comment: @sabbir For the first way `SELECT MAX(column) as \`column\`, second, third, ..` for the second query, try `print_r( $row)` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. By Index or by Column Name. If you really want to use a column name, alias the column in your query.

```
$sql = mysql_query(" SELECT MAX(column) `max` FROM tableName WHERE variable='$var' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Then you can use

```
$row['max'];
```

or

```
$row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not returning any rows. You should try WHERE variable LIKE '%$var%';

Answer (score 0):

```
     $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT MAX(column) AS GIVE_A_NAME FROM tableName WHERE variable='$var' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

and

```
      echo "Maximum value is ::  ".$row['GIVE_A_NAME'];
```